# Why can't refresh away the text in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Can have a try [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php).

Whatever you entered into the editor will remain there after refreshing,

Anyone knows the trick?

**UPDATE**

[doctype](http://doctype.com/problem-ajax-php-please-help#answer_5930) also has this feature.

Comment: It only does it in Firefox for me, not Chrome or IE.

Comment: Try doctype, it happens in IE/firefox

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply delete the editor text onload?

Ex.

```
<body onload="javascript:tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');">
```

Comment: this won't work because the editor instance won't be initialized at that point of time